# Connect to aws remote Postgres from Java jdbc with ssh tunnel, Facing connection timeout, while JsCH session.connect() ran successful

Tags: java, postgresql, amazon-web-services, jdbc, database-connection

`Hi Guys,

I am facing Connection Timeout at DriverManager.getConnection() while connecting to aws remote postgresql database. It involves SSH too, i am facing issue while connecting through java, as DBeaver is able to connect successfully.

Tried below code while expecting connection successful.

```
String url = "jdbc:postgresql://###remoteHost";
        String userName = "userName";
        String password = "pwd";
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
      
        
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            String jumpserverHost = "sshHost";
            String jumpserverUsername = "sshUsername";
            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            jsch.addIdentity("FileContainingKey");
            

            Session session = jsch.getSession(jumpserverUsername, jumpserverHost, 22);
            session.setConfig(props);
            session.connect();

            // Forward randomly chosen local port through the SSH channel to database host/port
            int forwardedPort = session.setPortForwardingL(8080, "remoteHost", 5432);
            System.out.println(forwardedPort);// 8080 
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+":"+forwardedPort+"/ulp?ssl=true", userName, password);
            
            System.out.println("Connected to the PostgreSQL server successfully.");
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          }
```

But getting connection timeout error as below:-

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:315)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:225)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:465)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:264)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
    at application.DBTesting.connectionSetup(DBTesting.java:193)
    at util.MainFrameClass.main(MainFrameClass.java:25)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:546)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:333)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:645)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:231)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:95)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:98)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:213)
    ... 8 more
```

`

Comment: Looks like  url = "jdbc:postgresql://###remoteHost"; - should simply point to localhost not remoteHost - jdbc:postgresql://localhost:8080/ulp?ssl=true

Comment: Thank you so much!! It worked!! localhost was the change to be made....

Answer (score 0):

Looks like url = "jdbc:postgresql://###remoteHost"; - should simply point to localhost not remoteHost - jdbc:postgresql://localhost:8080/ulp?ssl=true –
Vicctor
This worked for me ......